# Timeline modal operator: how to get frame cursor to follow mouse

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to write a modal operator for the timeline, but I'm confused about how to get the current frame cursor in the timeline to follow a 'mousemove' event (and consequently, how to set the new current frame when the operator finishes).

Answer (score 1):

Solved - 
in the invoke() function, I set these:

```
self._initial_mouse = event.mouse_x
self._initial_frame = scene.frame_current
```

in modal():

```
self.offset = (self._initial_mouse - event.mouse_x) * -0.1
scene.frame_current = self._initial_frame + self.offset
```